# How is the time complexity of a nested for loop n^2 +1?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

So I was reviewing some slides my teacher gave us and we are given the following Python code:

```
a=5
b=6
c=10
```

```
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
      x = i * j
      y = j * j
      z = i * j
```

```
for k in range(n):
   w = a*k + 45
   v = b*b
```

```
d=33
```

For the first part (variable declaration) the time complexity is constant, so *O(1)* or for the purposes of writing the whole thing as an equation at the end, 3. And same for the last part with 1.

Now, for the second and third parts is where my question comes in. The second part apparently has a *3n^2 + 2* time complexity and the third one a *2n + 1*. I know that the *3n^2* and *2n* come from the number of variables inside the loops (because they get iterated that many times, and in the nested one that makes it *n***n*).

But I just don't know where the *+ 2* and *+ 1* come from.

I've tried looking up how come a `for loop` in Python is *n+1* but not a single site so far describes it like that, I think it's because all of them give the **general** time complexity, which of course I get that it's *O(n)*, but part of my assignment is to give the **specific** one as well and that's where the constants come in.

My guess is that the *n* comes from the `range(n)` part rather than from the `for i in` itself, and thus that declaration of the `for` is essentially like any other variable declarations (constant) but I'm really not sure and would like to understand why.

(If you don't feel like giving out a full explanation I'd be fine with just any link to some site/video that does so).

Thank you :)

Comment: If you are counting operations in any sense you have to define what an operation is. Is the setup-cost of the loop included? Are assignments included? A real python program will also have costs that do not correspond to lines of user-code, especially related to memory management.

And to interpret that "operations-count" is questionable,  because it depends on arbitrary definitions (that probably have little to do with actual performance metrics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula for a for loop: `x*n+1`.
`x` - number of operations performs for each iteration.
`n` - number of iterations
`+1` - creating range obj.

So in your case the formula is `1 + n(3n + 1)` <=>`1 + 3n^2 + n`.
creating main loop range obj + n iterations * (3 operations * n iterations + creating 1 range object)

The time complexity depends on programming language you are computing it for.

Source: [http://math.uni.wroc.pl/~jagiella/p2python/skrypt_html/wyklad2-1.html](http://math.uni.wroc.pl/%7Ejagiella/p2python/skrypt_html/wyklad2-1.html)

Comment: This clears it up, thank you!